# How to use host property of angular directive to submit form? Is it good choice for unit testing too?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have searched a lot on the internet and I would say that i have not found anything like this anywhere. May be I am lost and don't know anything about it.

The question is:

**How to submit the form using host property of directive's metadata?**

Here goes my form template:

```html
<form #userlogin="ngForm" [class.hidden]="!isActiveTab" login-form novalidate>
  <h3>System Login</h3>
  <ul>
    <li><input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control"></li>
    <li><input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control"></li>
    <li><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Login</button></li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

As you can see I have placed a directive on form element `login-form` and i have created a directive:

```js
import { Directive, Renderer2, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[login-form]',
  host: {
    "(submit)": "onSubmit()"
  }
})
export class LoginformDirective {

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef) {}

  onSubmit() {
    console.log('How to get form here!!!');
  }

}
```

So, **I want to know How to submit form such way? and Is it good for Unit Testings?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply inject it:

```
export class LoginformDirective {
    constructor(..., private form: NgForm) { ... }

      onSubmit() {
          this.form
      }
```

Each directive in Angular defines itself as a provider on an element the directive is applied to. The `form` element is targeted by the `NgForm` directive:

```
@Directive({
    selector: 'form:not([ngNoForm]):not([formGroup]),ngForm,[ngForm]',
    providers: [formDirectiveProvider],
    host: {'(submit)': 'onSubmit($event)', '(reset)': 'onReset()'},
    outputs: ['ngSubmit'],
    exportAs: 'ngForm'
})
export class NgForm extends ControlContainer ... {
    onSubmit($event: Event): boolean {
        (this as{submitted: boolean}).submitted = true;
        syncPendingControls(this.form, this._directives);
        this.ngSubmit.emit($event);
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: i have to wait for another 3 mins but Is it good for unit tests. such way if i submit the form.

Comment: @Jai, it's subjective of course, but I don't see any problems with it. DI dependencies are easily mocked and with such implementation you're decoupling the logic of submitting a form from the component that houses the form. It means that submit handler logic can be reused across many forms

Comment: Hmm...Sounds interesting is there anything else i should take care of? just getting curious about it. I would be glad if you suggest something about it.

Comment: @Jai, sorry, don't know what else to add :). As I said, the solution seems reasonable to me

Comment: absolutely. Thanks again.

Comment: @Jai, just added a piece of `NgForm` implementation. As you can see it uses similar approach to your directive and binds to `submit` event. It will  be called before yours, so your implementation shouldn't have any undesirable consequences.

Answer (score 0):

An appropriate way to solve this problem is to use HostListener

```
@HostListener('submit')
onSubmit() {
    console.log('Form has been submitted');
}
```

You can do this in a directive.